# Get Most Popular Search Terms from PageEvent xDB

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I have manually trigger a search event based on Sitecore in standart way:

```
var searchEvent = Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.PageEvents[AnalyticsIds.SearchEvent.Guid];

Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Register(new PageEventData(searchEvent.Alias, searchEvent.Id)
{
    Data = "sitecore experience platform"
});
```

but after I need to find the most popular or latest search,
not for one specific ContactReference, but globally by site.
how I could do it programmatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all SearchEvents you will need to make a call to XConnect.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
using (XConnectClient xConnectClient = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
{
    var searchs = new List<SearchEvent>();
    Guid SearchDefinitionID = new Guid("0c179613-2073-41ab-992e-027d03d523bf");
    var interactions = await xConnectClient.Interactions.Where(interaction => interaction.Events.Any(ev => ev.DefinitionId == SearchDefinitionID)).ToList();
    foreach (var interaction in interactions)
    {
        foreach (SearchEvent ev in interaction.Events.Where(ev => ev.DefinitionId == SearchDefinitionID).ToList())
        {
            searchs.Add(ev);
        }
    }
}
```

If you are going to be doing regular data extraction and processing from XConnect. I believe it is recommended to use the Sitecore Cortex engine and its projection framework:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-platform/projection-framework.html

You could use this to project, group and count data as required. This uses distributed workers, so can be alot faster and more efficient.

I found this to be a great resource if you are interested in the above:
https://github.com/adeneys/cortex-processing-demo